# How can I label my nodes with two splitted squares

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How can I create two little boxes above/below my nodes like those? I already wrote a label, but it didn´t work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{29AB87}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{9F0101}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{1C4966}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=mygreen, fill=mygreen!50, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
    squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=myred, fill=myred!50, very thick, minimum size=5mm},
    square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4},
    ]

    %Nodes
    \node at ( 0,0) [roundnode] (node0) {0};
    \node at ( 3,0)[roundnode] (node1) {1} [label={[draw,rectangle split,%<-selects shape
        rectangle split parts=2,%<- 2 node parts
        rectangle split horizontal,%<- horizontal split
        yshift=-1ex]above:{10\nodepart{two}10}}];;;
    \node at ( 3,3) [roundnode] (node2) {2};
    \node at ( 6,3)[roundnode] (node3) {3};
    \node at ( 3,-3)[roundnode] (node4) {4};


    %Lines
    \draw[->] (node0) --node [text width=1.5cm,midway,above=0em] {A(19,0.45)}(node1);
    \draw[->, very thick, myred] (node0) -- node [text width=1.5cm,midway,above=-0.20em, rotate=45, black] {B(19,0.45)}(node2);
    \draw[->, very thick, myred] (node2) -- node [text width=1.5cm,midway,above=0em, black] {C(19,0.45)}(node3);
    \draw[->][dashed] (node1) -- (node2);
    \draw[->] (node0) -- node [text width=1.5cm,midway,above=0em, rotate=-45] {D(19,0.45)}(node4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can u please draw a hand sketch to show the desired result-- u had asked a similar query which was answered earlier

Comment: I already have done it! But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add `[<options>]` anywhere. In your code you have

```
\node at (x,y) [<some style options>]  {<node text>} [<label>];
```

but you can't have options after the `{<node text>}`, the `label` should go along with the other options you've added to the node previously.

```
\node at (x,y) [<some style options>, <label>] {<node text>};
```

As a sidenote, the documented order is

```
\node [<options>] at (<coordinate>) {<node text>};
```

though it does work as you've written it as well.

For the specific code in your question:

```
\node at ( 3,0)[roundnode, label={[draw,rectangle split,%<-selects shape
    rectangle split parts=2,%<- 2 node parts
    rectangle split horizontal,%<- horizontal split
    yshift=-1ex]below:{10\nodepart{two}10}}] (node1) {1};
```

You also need to add `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}` library to the preamble in order to use `rectangle split`.

Comment: Thank you for those tips. I already did it. You were really helpful.

Comment: @davids_73, you should at least up-vote this answer,  and also considering to accept it.

Comment: Sorry @Zarko, I´m new here on stack Exchange. I didn´t know that it was so important to vote up for a comment.

Comment: @davids_73 If it's useful, consider upvoting, if it solved the problem (or in the case where there are multiple answers, solved the problem in the best way for you), consider accepting, by clicking the checkmark on the left.   (That said, not sure why you call my answer a comment, it was intended as a solution to your problem by explaining what you had done wrong, and what you needed to do to fix it.)